# PHP base64 decode returns garbage characters

Tags: php

I'm decoding a string that was encoded in Python.

When using an online simulator for the decoding: https://www.base64decode.org/

The correct value is presented but when I'm decoding it on my end using PHP `base64_decode` it returns garbage characters:

> ["(","bean_id","=��M�MM̋LY �KM X�KNX��KY��X��L؍ ��H�

I'm guessing this has something to do with my charset?

The encoded string:

> WyIoIiwiYmVhbl9pZCIsIj0+IiwiMDAxN2E1NzItMWQ2NS00NWJhLTljNzEtZGRmNmFiMzkzYjQ0IiwiKSJd

When decoded using the online simulator results in this:

> ["(","bean_id","=>","0017a572-1d65-45ba-9c71-ddf6ab393b44",")"]

My code:

```
$page = $_GET['code'];
$plainText = base64_decode($page);

echo $plainText;
```

Additional information:

The problem occurs when I fetch the string from the url.

Comment: I got desired result with your code where $page was the encoded string. You can check $page by echo it since it's base 64 encoded.

Comment: Yep, I got the correct result as well: `php > echo base64_decode("WyIoIiwiYmVhbl9pZCIsIj0+IiwiMDAxN2E1NzItMWQ2NS00NWJhLTljNzEtZGRmNmFiMzkzYjQ0IiwiKSJd");`
`["(","bean_id","=>","0017a572-1d65-45ba-9c71-ddf6ab393b44",")"]`

Comment: Could this be a setup problem for my server?

Comment: Works fine for me https://ideone.com/jhjhXe

Comment: It works fine for encodings that use one byte for ASCII characters (iso-latin-*, utf-8): https://3v4l.org/F92lk Are you using UTF-16?

Comment: @axiac Where do I check that?

Comment: Sorry everyone it seems like the problem occurs when the string to be decoded is fetched from the URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was fetching the string in the URL using `$_GET`

Since it's in the URL the `+` will be transformed into a  (Space)

That was causing the garbage character.

What I'm doing now to avoid this problem is to use `urlencode` on my string after `$_GET` so that the transformed characters will be returned to their original form.

Working late really has its downside. Thank you, everyone.

Comment: The same for me, $_GET param which include `+` was converted into ` `

Answer (score 0):

**How to remove ^ b" on base64 decode?**

**I got the best solutions by following**

*At first encode like following sequence*

```
JSON Encode > URL Encode > Base64 Encode
```

*Now you can decode safely by following sequence*

```
Base64 Decode > URL Decode > JSON Decode
```

It will encode the special characters if exists. and you will not find any garbage like `^ b" ...`